# Excel VBA - Writing 3rd to 6th dimension of one element to a Range

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

In excel VBA, given a 2D array:

```
[1,a,1,2,3]    
[2,b,4,5,6]    
[3,c,7,8,9]
```

I look for a match in the array, and if found, I need to write the right three dimensions to the sheet.

So if I find "b", then I need to write "4", "5", and "6" to a range that is 1 row by 3 columns, offset by one column to the right of the active cell.

```
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 3)).Value = Application.Index(carray, cindex)
```

This code lets me write the entire element, but is there a way to write a subset of dimensions within an element without looping?

Alternatively, is there a non-looping way to copy and truncate the first 2 dimensions to another array? If I have the same number of elements, cindex would be the same, and that would solve the problem as well.

Other solution recommendations welcome. I could loop, but I have to traverse multiple sheets in the workbook, so I was hoping for a one-liner for simplicity. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a largely hard-coded approach, but may give you a clue as to how to explore further. I populated the array from a sheet to save time, but it needn't be done like that.

```
Sub x()

Dim v As Variant, n As Variant

v = Range("A1:E3")

With Range("H2")
    n = Application.Match(.Value, Application.Index(v, , 2), 0)
    .Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(v, 2)-2).Value = Application.Index(v, n, Array(3, 4, 5))
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi SJR, thank you. I think this is close, but I am getting #N/A columns I, J, and K, and nothing in column H. I see n should hold the match of v, but I do not see where we are matching the "b" in

    n = Application.Match(.Value, Application.Index(v, , 2), 0)

Comment: Hi SJR. It took me a few minutes, but I now see how it works! The example is coded to have search value in H2! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works. You might find this thread a useful reference https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/758402-vba-working-with-areas-within-2d-arrays.html

Comment: I have an added wrinkle. what if ubound(v,2) is variable from sheet to sheet, so  I have a variable number of columns and therefore the static 3-column Application.Index(v, n, Array(3, 4, 5))  won't work. I think I'm back to writing a loop.

Comment: You may need a loop. You can use a variable in place of `Array(3, 4, 5)` so eg. `v1=array(3,4,5,6)` and then `.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(v1) + 1).Value = Application.Index(v, n, v1)` so you could do a check first. Make sense? That said, if you're using arrays rather than the worksheet a loop isn't much of an overhead.